# "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6" The common fixes don't work,

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, steam, libraries

So I know this is a problem that has been asked around a lot, but I've tried a bunch of solutions with no success. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit), and I just installed it yesterday. This is my first time working with linux.

The error is: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6

Things I've tried. First, I had downloaded from the steam website. I uninstalled it, and tried again from the ubuntu software centre.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This installed a bunch of the 32 bit libraries, but did not fix the issue. This seems like the major fix for most people. The direct approach of

```
sudo apt-get install libc.so.6
```

returns this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc.so.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libc.so.6'
```

I guess libc.so.6 isn't a package, just a single file or something? I also tried

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf
```

Added these two lines, those the second one was all ready in the file, but copied over:

```
/usr/lib32
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
```

Then executed:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

But nothing seemed to happen, steam still doesn't work.

So, I feel like it is more likely that I have the library and steam isn't looking in the right place. One thing I've seen is people usually reference /usr/local/lib/ for your library locations. However, I can't find where to cd into /usr/, it isn't in my home folder. If /usr/ is the home folder, there is only a /.local folder which only has /share, no lib anywhere. Sorry for my linux ignorance.

I appreciate any help, I honestly have no idea how to confirm I have the library and point steam to it, or if that is even the right thing to do.

Edit: Tried this, not entirely sure what it means

```
~$ ls -l /lib32/libc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1721832 Sep 30 11:06 /lib32/libc-2.15.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  185928 Sep 30 11:06 /lib32/libcidn-2.15.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Sep 30 11:06 /lib32/libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.15.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   34316 Sep 30 11:06 /lib32/libcrypt-2.15.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Sep 30 11:06 /lib32/libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.15.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Sep 30 11:06 /lib32/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.15.so
```

Comment: Steam is installable via apt-get at least on Trusty - and it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`?

Comment: I meant `libc6:i386`.

Comment: Yes Balgerda, I've tried that and it doesn't install anything new. Which I presume means I have the libraries needed, steam just can't find them.

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD=/lib32/libc.so.6 steam` but this gives me `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

then retry these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Also, you can try

```
sudo apt-get install libc-bin:i386
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Steam, and I tried this command for an other problem with my webcam:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring
```

I had to restart my computer and after this, it worked!
I think it was a problem with the kernel, I don't really know what it is, but thanks to the ubuntu coommunity.

Comment: Raring Ringtail ended support few days after this answer was given. It might have lead to a solution when Raring was supported. Now it is in any case irrelevant and should not mislead new readers that come here looking for solutions.

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo apt-get install curl 
sudo apt-get install jockey-common
```

Comment: Can you add more information?

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related to missing i386 libraries for Steam.